# Unity timeScale

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, simulation

I am creating a solar system simulator using Unity 2021.
Unity timeScale is by **default 1 which translates to 1 second in real-time**. There is a cap in the Editor of 100, **which means that 1 second in real time equals 100 seconds in the simulation.**

Now as you can imagine this cap is way too low for a "space" simulation.
Does anyone have a way or suggestion on how to circumvent this cap?

I understand how the Unity Time API works but I do not seem to find a way to achieve this.

A good example of the result desired would be the timeScale in *Universe sandbox* which if I am not mistaken was developed in Unity.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way this can be done is the way Kerbal Space Program handles time warps up to 100,000x, which is to do the calculations for where the spacecraft should be after a specified amount of time without calculating it every in-game frame (as shown [here](https://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Time_warp)). This method will not allow the spacecraft to be under complex physical forces such as atmospheric drag, but it can simulate accurately the predictable trajectories spacecraft go through during space travel.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
After the time warp lets say the earth object just teleports to its calculated position or does it maybe Lerp to that position or something of the sort?